# How to apply a library command on each row and create a new variable

Tags: r, plyr

I'm having a little trouble creating a new variable using a command within the ineq() library, which calculates a Gini coefficient.  The vector I give the ineq command is a list of the columns I'm interested in.  I want to run this command for each individual row and then append the new variable.

When I attempt this as a loop or using a ddply (which I'm just learning now), the output is the same Gini score (for the entire data set) for each row.

**How can I run this command for each individual row?**  Thanks in advance!

```
library(ineq)
df <- data.frame( user = 1:5, v1 = c(2,4,6,8,10), v2 = c(1,5,11,5,1), v3 = c(3,1,2,7,9))

for (i in nrow(df)) {
  df$gini <- ineq(c(df$v1, df$v2, df$v3))
}

myGini <- ddply(df, .(user), gini=ineq(c(v1, v2, v3)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this package or the function, but the function you are looking for is probably `apply()`:

```
df <- data.frame( user = 1:5, v1 = c(2,4,6,8,10), v2 = c(1,5,11,5,1), v3 = c(3,1,2,7,9))
df$gini <- apply(df[,-1],1,ineq)
```

EDIT:

Also, the reason why your loop did not work was twofold, first you need to use indexing inside the loop, second you need to loop for a vector: 1:nrow(df) instead of just nrow(df):

```
df <- data.frame( user = 1:5, v1 = c(2,4,6,8,10), v2 = c(1,5,11,5,1), v3 = c(3,1,2,7,9))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$gini[i] <- ineq(c(df$v1[i], df$v2[i], df$v3[i]))
}
```

Comment: the code above will include the `user` column in the `ineq` calculation, which isn't what the OP is after I don't think. You could modify your code to `df$gini <- apply(df[, -1],1,ineq)` to calculate `ineq` on `v1` `v2` and `v3`.

Comment: I guess I edited this when you were typing the comment (or the other way around) :)

Answer (score 3):

You were very close with what you had previously. You were missing the argument `transform` which adds columns to an existing data frame. `summarise` is another handy function to use with the plyr functions.

```
myGini <- ddply(df, .(user), transform, gini=ineq(c(v1, v2, v3)))
```

Alternatively, you can treat your data.frame as an array and operate on a row by row basis:

```
adply(df, 1, transform, gini = ineq(c(v1, v2, v3)))

or

adply(df, 1, function(x) gini = ineq(x[-1]))
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with plyr, is `adply` the same as `apply` but for arrays? Or are there differences in speed as well?

Comment: @Sacha - I'm going to defer to the [website](http://had.co.nz/plyr/) and specifically the [intro guide](http://had.co.nz/plyr/plyr-intro-090510.pdf) for the specifics, but in my opinion - the benefits of the `plyr` package are that you can explicitly define the input and output types. I often find myself futzing around with the base `apply` family trying to coerce to and from lists, etc. I'm not in the know about any performance benefits, but I don't recall anyone saying the `plyr` is SLOWER than the base apply functions, so I don't think you'd be losing any performance.

Comment: Also, performance is the __last__ thing you should be optimising, not the first.  You code will double in speed in 18 months, but it won't get any easier to understand.